# regex matching strings of the form abc|abc

Tags: regex

whats a regex pattern that matches the same string repeated, with both instances separated by a pipe char?
Example strings that the regex should match:
a|a
abc|abc

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backreference to match what's captured in a prior capture group:

```
(.+)\|\1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RZEQcm/2

Comment: Without `^` [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` it will match eg `b|b` in `a|b|b`.